# Proof by strong induction involving a piecewise function

Tags: proof-writing, induction, solution-verification, fibonacci-numbers

I was wondering if my proof for the following question is valid:

Let $F(n)$ be the Fibonacci sequence

> $F(n)=\begin{cases}
>           n \quad &\text{if} \, n < 2 \\
>           F(n-2)+F(n-1) \quad &\text{if} \, n \ge 2 \\
>      \end{cases}$

Prove that $\forall \in \mathbb{N}$, $F(n) \leq 2^n$.

### **Proof:**

Let $P(n): F(n) \leq 2^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Base Case:** 
$n=0, F(n) =0 \leq 2^0 = 1$ 
$n=1, F(n) =1 \leq 2^1 = 2$

**Inductive Hypothesis:** 
Suppose $P(0), P(1), P(2), ..., P(k)$ is true for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Inductive Step:** 
We want to show that:
$F(k+1)=\begin{cases}
          n \quad &\text{if} \, k+1 < 2 \\
          F(k-1)+F(k) \quad &\text{if} \, k+1 \ge 2 \\
     \end{cases} \leq 2^{k+1}$.

Thus, consider $F(k+1)$. Assume $k+1 < 2$, then using our **inductive we hyptohesis** we get: $$F(k+1)=k + 1 \leq 2^k + 1 \leq 2^k+2 \leq 2 \cdot 2^k = 2^{k+1}$$
This completes this case.

Now, assume $k+1 \ge 2$, then $F(k+1) = F(k-1) + F(k)$. By our **inductive we hypothesis**,
$$F(k+1)=F(k-1) + F(k) \leq 2^{k-1} + 2^k \leq 2^k + 2^k = 2^{k+1}$$

Therefore the proof is now complete.

Thanks

Comment: Seems ok, but you don't need to deal with the case $k+1<2$ in the inductive step, since this case has been already done in the base case.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Is it handled by the base case because $k+1 < 2$ is equivalent to $k< 1$, which implies that it must be the case that $k=0$ which is is covered in the base case?

Comment: Yes. You can suppose that $k \geq 2$ at the beginning of the inductive step, since you already treated the other cases.